# Algorithm Analysis of Simple 2 Cases

Tags: algorithm

Well I am studying algorithms for an upcoming exam and I am having hard time verifying if the practices below are answered right.

```
 i=1
 while(i<=n)
      j=1
      while(j<i)
            j=j+1
      i=i*2
```

The answer of mine for this one is O(n.log n)

```
i=1
 while(i<=n)
      j=1
      while(j<i)
            j=j*2
      i=i+1
```

Again I have answered it as O(n.log n)

Can someone verify that I am answering correct or not ? Also any tips regarding analysis for future practices are welcome.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each of these is **O(n log n)**.  You have one loop that is a linear iteration, i.e. **O(n)**.  You have another loop that is exponential; the inverse is log, so that loop is **O(log n)**.  As they are nested, you multiple the complexities, and get **O(n log n)**.